# How do I retrieve a custom attribute value from a property reference.

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods, custom-attributes

I have defined a new custom attribute XPath, and applied that attribute to various properties of my class

```
public class Appointment
{
    [XPath("appt/@id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [XPath("appt/@uid")]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to reflect against the class as a whole to retrieve all of the attributes, but I would like a way to reflect against a particular property (preferably without passing in the string name of the property)

Optimally I would be able to create an extension method (or some other type of helper) that would allow me to do something like one of the following :

```
appointment.Id.Xpath();
```

or

```
GetXpath(appointment.Id)
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to get the `XPathAttribute` associated with a property:

```
var attr = (XPathAttribute)typeof(Appointment)
               .GetProperty("Id")
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XPathAttribute), true)[0];
```

You could wrap this in a method using an `Expression` like this:

```
public static string GetXPath<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (me != null)
    {
        var attr = (XPathAttribute[])me.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XPathAttribute), true);
        if (attr.Length > 0)
        {
            return attr[0].Value;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
GetXPath(() => appointment.Id)  // appt/@id
```

Or if you prefer to be able to call this without having an object instance to reference:

```
public static string GetXPath<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expr)
{
    var me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (me != null)
    {
        var attr = (XPathAttribute[])me.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XPathAttribute), true);
        if (attr.Length > 0)
        {
            return attr[0].Value;
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
GetXPath<Appointment>(x => x.Id); // appt/@id
```

Answer (score 1):

Second method should actually be:

```
   GetXPath<Appointment, long>(x => x.Id); // appt/@id
```

Comment: the second type parameter can be inferred by the compiler so is not required to be passed in